# mod rewrite .htaccess URL redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url

I want to simply point the www.mysite.com/corporate to www.mysite.com/services/corporate

here is my .htaccess:

```
#DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options -Indexes
#ErrorDocument 403 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^corporate$ services/corporate
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}  !^$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

#php_value register_globals 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mod_rewrite.` Place something like this in .htaccess in the root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/corporate/(.*)$ $1/services/corporate/$2 [R,L]
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand some parts of your .htaccess code but you can add one more line before `</IfModule>` there:

```
RewriteRule ^corporate/?$ services/corporate [NC,L,R=301]
```